# Not able to access $result and my defiened $data[] array same time in Codeigniter view file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

thnx in advance  i m fetching some record from db and tring to send that result in view with some other data i have already. but not sure how to access that result value in drop down list.

**Controller**

```
$xap = $this->captchaGen();
$data['states'] = $this->Register_model->ListStates();
$data1 = array(
    'captcha' => $xap['image'],
    'message' => '',
    'state' => $data
);
$this->load->view('login', $data1);
```

**VIEW**

```
foreach ($state as $row) {
    $options[$row->name] = $row->name;
}
$js = 'id="c_stat"  class="form-control"';
echo form_dropdown('c_stat', $options, set_value('c_stat'), $js);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Controller**

Pass  data to view as

```
 $xap=$this->captchaGen();
    $data['states'] = $this->Register_model->ListStates();
    $data['captcha'] = $xap['image'];
    $data['message'] = "";
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
```

**In views**

```
foreach ($states as $row)
{

}
```

Comment: what is in link? what we have to do there?i try to like your answer but stack showing i dont have reputation to like answer untill  i get 15.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try this** 

In controller 
$states = $this->Register_model->ListStates();
$data['captcha'] => $xap['image'];
$data['message'] => '';
$data['state'] => $states;

$this->load->view('login', $data);

And in view 
foreach ($state as  $value) {

}
```

**Pass $data in place of $data1**

$this->load->view('login', $data1);

**replace it with**

$this->load->view('login', $data);